# load balancing Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, networking, http

I have a very simple setup at home that's serving a website for some home/school projects. The setup has a DSL modem (M) with a static  IP address connected to a Netgear router (R) that port-forwards HTTP traffic to Apache on an Ubuntu machine (A) on my home intranet. I have now added another machine running Ubuntu (B) to my home network that I'd like to load balance the HTTP traffic to. These machines also do other heavy lifting for my intranet and thus can have a fluctuating load. So in ASCII art-

```
                                            (A:192.168.1.2- Ubuntu)
  Internet---(M:1.2.3.4)--(R:192.168.1.1)--/
                              Netgear      \
                                            (B:192.168.1.3- Ubuntu)
```

From an initial assessment it seems like there are several ways to do this- mod_proxy_balancer, apache clusters, external proxy, round robin DNS, or DNS proxies, etc. A lot of these solutions are designed with the possibility that the network will grow/scale. That's very unlikely in my case- and certainly not a requirement. What's the **simplest** way to setup load balancing between A and B machines?

For now a random distribution would be ok, but I'd like to eventually have more programmatic control (like failover, or pointing traffic based on some external factors like the load on the machines, or perhaps the URL, etc.) to setup rules on where the traffic gets directed to. I suspect as these requirements grow non-apache based solutions (like DNS-based) will not work but maybe I'm wrong with that assumption.

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: I can't imagine a situation where a properly configured web server could be a bottleneck for traffic over a DSL connection. What's the max upload speed for this connection?

Answer (score 1):

Run something like haproxy+ucarp on both machines, that will handle load balancing and failover just fine..

Answer (score 0):

The simplest would be to create two virtual web servers on each physical server - www.cgi and www.static.

Split web files into virtual directories, sync both servers.

1. CGI (PHP, Ruby, Java, Perl, ASP)
2. static files (images, favicons, javascript, css, flash, pdf, doc, txt, media, etc.)

There are three "heavy load" services now - Database, www.cgi and www.static.

- Run all three on either server.
- Run Database on server A and both web virtuals on server B.
- Run Database and www.cgi on Server A and www.static on server B.

Easy to manage, provides fail-over, no extra complexity until needed.

Generally, two machines are for fail-over, three or more machines for load balancing.

If you're using server class machines then hardware load balancing is usually cost effective and simple.

Answer (score 0):

Max upload is limited though not the bottleneck. The real problems come from other services (for my intranet) that often lead to hangs/failures on the server machines.If I have this setup right then I won't have significant downtimes for my web servers (which among other things run icecast radio streams that disconnects users)

@Colin Thanks for the info on linuxvirtualserver.org I'm going to check that out.

@Joe I'm not sure I get your solution- If server A dies, then my CGI is dead (or similarly with B), where is the failover? And no I don't have server class hardware- just old (and diverse) "retired" PCs that work fine with Ubuntu.